# How can i plot an undirected connected graph in R?

Tags: r, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I want to plot graph (which is an undirected  connected graph) like the uploaded picture.

I want to use the adjacency matrix in order to plot it.

So my question is how can I plot a graph from its adjacency matrix.

Ideally I want the plot to look like the attached picture.

I tried the igraph package in R :

```
data <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0,1,
                 1,0,1,0,0,
                 0,1,0,1,0,
                 0,0,1,0,1,
                 1,0,0,1,0),nrow=5,ncol = 5)
colnames(data) = rownames(data) = LETTERS[1:5]
data

network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data)


plot(network)
```

But it creates a cycle.

Any help ?

[image]

Comment: Beware. Try changing the last "1" of the first row to "2", display the matrix and see what happens. Matrix(...) reads the array column by column. Use matrix(..., byrow=TRUE) if otherwise intended.

Comment: It plots a cycle because you gave the adjacency matrix of a cycle. Why did you expect something else? To produce an undirected graph, use `mode='undirected'` in `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()`. You can look this up in the documentation of `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()`. Note that "undirected strongly connected" doesn't make sense. We only talk about strongly or weakly connected graphs when dealing with directed graphs.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and clarify what you want to do? Do you want to plot the graph created from your adjacency matrix? Do you want to find the adjacency matrix of the graph you show in the image? Do you want to just create the graph shown in the image, but you don't care about the adj. mat.? What did you actually mean when you said "undirected strongly connected"?

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edited my question.I am newbie in Graph Theory so I apologize for my mistake in the "strongly" connected phrase that I used in my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only the upper (or lower) triangle of the matrix to be 1, but 0 elsewhere. Make sure you also set `mode = "upper"`

```r
library(igraph)

data <- matrix(0, 5, 5, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:5]))
data[upper.tri(data)] <- 1

data
#>   A B C D E
#> A 0 1 1 1 1
#> B 0 0 1 1 1
#> C 0 0 0 1 1
#> D 0 0 0 0 1
#> E 0 0 0 0 0

network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data, mode = 'upper')

plot(network)
```

[image]

Or, if you want a much more customized appearance (I think your sketch has a nicer aesthetic than the default igraph plot), use `ggraph`:

```r
library(ggraph)

ggraph(network) +
  geom_edge_link(aes(label = paste0('a', 1:10)), angle_calc = 'along',
                 vjust = -0.5, label_colour = 'red') +
  geom_node_circle(aes(r = 0.1), fill = "#dbdccf") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), color = 'blue4', fontface = 2,
                 size = 8) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_graph() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(color = NA, fill = "#f5f6e9"),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = 'gray90'),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(size = 0.5, color = 'gray90'))
```

[image]

Comment: Why I need only the upper elements of the adjacency matrix?Because otherwise it will direct the path in both connected vertices?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson because you want a single link between, say, B and C, so you want row B to have a 1 in column C. If you also have a 1 in row C, column B (in the lower triangle), then this will be another link between B and C, so you will have two. Sticking to the upper triangle gives a single link between each pair. If you have both the upper and lower triangles, each pair is represented twice.

Comment: The interpretation of the adjacency matrix depends, among other things, on the keywords: directed, undirected, max, upper, lower, min, plus.  See `help(graph_from_adjacency_matrix)`.

Comment: Given the default settings you can use upper triangle, lower triangle or both, with the same result as in `graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, "undirected")`.  Note
`g8 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjm, mode="plus")` sums the lower and upper triangles.

Comment: @AllanCameron In the next version of igraph, using `mode='undirected'` with a non-symmetric matrix will throw an error. If you only want to consider the upper part of the matrix, you should use `mode='upper'`.  It would be great if you could change the first part of your answer so it wouldn't cause confusion in the future.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for that. I have changed to `mode = 'upper'`. I notice that this mode includes the diagonal, which would then still have to be set to 0.

Comment: `mode` has no impact on the interpretation of the diagonal. That is controlled by the `diag` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `make_full_graph` from `igraph` package, e.g.,

```
n <- 5
make_full_graph(n) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "name", value = head(LETTERS, n)) %>%
  plot()
```

or, if you ***REALLY*** want to start from an ***adjacency matrix***

```
n <- 5
`dimnames<-`(1 - diag(n), rep(list(head(LETTERS, n)), 2)) %>%
  graph_from_adjacency_matrix("undirected") %>%
  plot()
```

which yields
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the matrix as follows:

```
data <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,1,
                 1,0,1,1,1,
                 1,1,0,1,1,
                 1,1,1,0,1,
                 1,1,1,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=5)
```

[image]

**Edit**

To remove the direction, as Allan Cameron recommended (option `mode='undirected'`.

```
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data, mode='undirected')
plot(network)
```

[image]

Comment: I think this gives you two opposite-directed edges between each pair of nodes rather than a single, undirected edge.

Comment: @AllanCameron You are right, I think your answer with option `mode = "undirected"` is perfect